# laravel 5.6 with angular 6 integration

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I want to use laravel(as backend) and angular(as frontend). 
As far as I know I can use 2 methods :-

1) I can integrate both frameworks by using API service or

2) I can use monolithic architecture style (using angular with blade template)

As per my requirements 2nd option is better because in it I can use laravel's default functionalities in angular like (Auth, user roles and permissions etc).

But I afraid that 2nd option makes the project complex and messy in future.

which is the better option?

Comment: What do you mean replace blade with angular? Angular is a frontend JS framework while blade is a templating engine for PHP. You can use both of them.

Comment: yes thanks, I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

I have used myself Laravel with Angular v2+, the way I did was to make two separate projects, one which creates the API's (The Laravel app) and one which consumes the API's (Angular v6 app). That is how it is meant to work and that is how you should approach it.
If you want to integrate the front with the back end, and still have a powerful SPA, then you can go with VueJS, there are vast resources when it comes to the Laravel Vue combination.

Comment: Whats matter ! if we place angular build in the laravel public folder and use laravel and angular both without backend api

Comment: @WaqasAhmed Then how will you manage angular routing in that case ?

Answer (score 2):

another thing to consider is what is this project about?

is it a client website? or just a web app? does it require SEO? beware.
make sure you fully understand (angular) universal and it's current limitations/problems.

UPDATE: I am currently using Angular 6 with with Server side rendering(universal) and a Laravel API as a Backend solution for a complex & highly ranked website in the UK.

Comment: how do u can use server side rendering universal using laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You have API routes available which doesn't look for CSRF tokens. Use any JWT package for web token authentication implementation. Host your Angular app separately and send request to API routes.

Your Angular apps are standalone applications. They don't need Laravel for running on server. You just need to use API routes for working with data.